# Robot Framework Suite

Tags: api, robotframework

I have 15 separate API Tests in Robot Framework. I want to create a Robot Test Suite and have all 15 tests within this suite so that I can run the .robot suite once and have all 15 tests run.

So suppose I have 3 separate tests :
1. Login.robot 
2. Get_customer_data.robot
3. Get_product_info.robot and I want to put all these tests in one suite such that when I run the suite it runs the three tests at once. Also, we use mocked data instead of a database so all the mocked data files currently lie within the respective test folders. 
For ex: theres a folder called Login which contains login_data (data files) and login.robot (Robot file). 
I was thinking I will create a suite with all the .robot files and retain the data files in the respective folders for the suite to access them when the suite is run. I was wondering if this is right and if there is a document that could help me figure this out. Please Help

Could someone kindly help?

Comment: What kind of help do you need? Have you tried putting all of the tests in one file?

Comment: I need help with setting up a robot framework suite which contains all the tests and running the suite tests the entire set of tests.

Comment: So suppose I have 3 separate tests :

Comment: I don't understand your question. I have robot tests suites with dozens of tests. Please show the smallest possible example of what you're struggling with.

Comment: Do not add additional information in an answer. The answer section is strictly for answers. You can [edit]  your original question.

Comment: Also, make sure you use the right terminology. When you say "15 separate API Tests", do you literally mean _test_, or do you mean "15 separate.robot files"? And when you say "run the .robot suite once", do you literally mean a single file with the suffix ".robot", or are you aware that a folder can be a suite, too?

Comment: I mean 15 different API tests. All of them have their own data files and .robot files. So from my example 1. login folder looks something like this: It has a data file called details.py containing the username and password. It has the login.robot file. I want to consolidate all these .robot files from the 15 tests, create a robot suite, retain the folders for the data files such that I can run the suite and all the 15 .robot tests run without me having the run them individually. I am sorry if I am not explaining correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Your question mentions having 15 different tests it appears that what you really have are 15 different robot test *suites* (ie: 15 different files with the `.robot` suffix) based on a comment you wrote.

The simplest way to combine them into a suite that you can run all at once is to put them in a directory. You can then tell robot to run the directory and it will find all of the `.robot` files and run them.

For example:

```
tests
└── api
    ├── Get_customer_data
    │   ├── customer_data
    │   └── Get_customer_data.robot
    ├── Get_product_info
    │   ├── Get_product_info.robot
    │   └── product_data
    ├── Login
    │   ├── login_data
    │   └── Login.robot
    └── ...
```

If you cd to the `tests` folder, you can do `robot api` and it will run all of the .robot files in that folder. Or, from the parent of the `tests` folder you can do `robot tests/api`.

Test suite directories are thoroughly documented in the robot framework user guide, in a section titled [Test suite directories](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#test-suite-directories)

Comment: I will try this. THanks

Answer (score 0):

There's actually an easy way to do this from the command line using pybot. I've verified this with Pycharm.

First, put all of your .robot files in a single folder. Then on the command line, instead of typing `pybot TestSuite/Test1.robot`, type `pybot TestSuite/*`. This will run all of the tests in (I observed) alphabetical order.

It may be alphabetical order because that's the order they were in my folder and not because it actually runs them that way, but to fix that prefix each test with a number, like `1_Login.robot`, `2_Get_customer_data.robot` ,`3_Get_product_info.robot`. This will execute everything in the numerical order. If you have more than 10, use 01, 02, 03, etc. to make sure everything works properly.

To have a one-click action to run this, you could put that line into a .cmd file, but that may be outside the scope of your question.